# SharePoint 2013 designer site workflow Modified By column not updating

Tags: 2013, workflow

I created a site workflow on task announcement list.It is an approval reject workflow which I created.

I have an issue after approval or reject step.

The Modified By date is still showing The initiator name, even after multiple time approval attempts. Can any one please suggest a resolution?

Comment: Hello.  Was there ever a fix or response to this question?  I am experiencing the same.